# How to maintain the atomicity of the pinned code in LLVM

Tags: llvm, volatile, llvm-ir

I used my own pass to insert some instructions into the basic block of the program. After the executable file was generated, disassembly could find that the order of some insert instructions was optimized, especially some inserting instructions were mixed with non-inserting instructions (the original instructions of the program). I would like to ask how can I disable the reordering of instructions and preserve the overall atomicity of my instrumentation code? Maybe optnone?
The instrumentation code like this:

```
/* Load */

      LoadInst *MapPtr = IRB.CreateLoad(MAP);
      MapPtr->setMetadata(M.getMDKindID("nosanitize"), MDNode::get(C, None));
      
/* Store */

      IRB.CreateStore(Num, MAP)
          ->setMetadata(M.getMDKindID("nosanitize"), MDNode::get(C, None));
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to do here, but [perhaps `volatile` helps](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#volatile-memory-accesses). You know that modern CPUs use concurrent and out-of-order execution, right? Instruction order isn't a simple sequence any more.

Comment: By "atomicity" of your code, you don't mean anything to do with atomic memory -- that is, memory which is accessed on multiple cores and you need certain guarantees to avoid conflict? Instead I think you mean that you want to add markers into the LLVM IR and not have them reordered in the matching assembly?

Comment: Imagine the challenge of converting a program from LISP to Prolog, for a moment. The task is to emit a program in prolog that performs the same task as the LISP. What does it mean to "preserve the order"? There never was a meaningful order to lose or to keep. LLVM thinks the same way, its task is to output assembly which performs the job the input code states, with the input code treated as a specification.

Comment: You need to write a program which actually has the behaviour you want. If you really want assembly marker tricks, you could insert inline assembly which LLVM can't reorder across and use those as markers in the assembly.

Comment: In fact, he reorder didn’t break the functionality of my code, but I would need to make subsequent changes to the executable binary, which might require that the order in which I inserted the code wouldn’t change. In executable binaries, the order will change for a variety of reasons, either optimization or machine platform. So I asked the question. I expected this to come down to hardware, but I wanted to see if it was possible. Now look, should not be ~ thank you for your answer!